# Java Swing - assignment (due pretty soon) inheritance and preview problem

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

I have an assignment to very soon and I think I went in over my head. I've tried looking places but its hard to describe my problem accurately. I'm new to swing and I don't know where the problem comes from exactly in m

My code has two major problems (although I wouldn't be surprised if there are more):

1. I can't access methods from one class to another despite them being package private
2. I can't see the drag and drop mode anymore (says that a line in one of my files is missing a ">" but its there)

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

```
package GUI;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

public class cleanup {
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private String notes;

    public cleanup(String c, String n, String no) {
        code = c;
        name = n;
        notes = no;
    }
    cleanup(int date, int time, char zone, int bags, String n, String no) {
        code = String.valueOf(date + time + zone + bags);
        name = n;
        notes = no;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public String getDate(){
        return code.substring(0,1) + "/" + code.substring(2,3) + "/" + code.substring(4,5);
    }
    public int getTime(){
        return parseInt(code.substring(6,7) + ":" + code.substring(8,9));
    }
    public String getTimeString(){
        return code.substring(6,7) + ":" + code.substring(8,9);
    }
    public char getZone(){
        return code.charAt(10);
    }
    public String getZoneString() { return Character.toString(code.charAt(10));}
    public int getBags(){
        return parseInt(code.substring(11,13));
    }
    public String getBagsString(){
        return code.substring(11,13);
    }
}
```

```
package GUI;

public class absence {
    private String name;
    private String code;

    public absence(String n, String c) {
        name = n;
        code = c;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

}
```

```
package GUI;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Interactive extends JFrame {
    private JButton addScheduledCleanupButton;
    private JButton addAbsenceButton;
    private JPanel bigPanel;
    private JList cleans;
    private JList absences;
    private JList urgency;
    private JList entityAnswers;
    private JList absName;
    private JList schZone;
    private JList zoneNames;
    private JList entityEntries;
    static ArrayList<cleanup> cleansList;
    static ArrayList<absence> absencesList;
    private LinkedList<String> urgencyList;
    private LinkedList<Integer> entityAnswersList;
    private LinkedList<String> absNameList;
    private LinkedList<Character> schZoneList;
    private char[] zoneNamesArray = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
    private String[] entityEntriesArray = {"Total number of bags  collected", "Number of bags this month", "Total number of cleanups", "Total hours of cleanup"};
    private DefaultListModel cleansListModel;
    private DefaultListModel absencesListModel;

    Interactive() {

        //Set up page
        super("ACTU Beach Cleanups");
        this.setContentPane(this.bigPanel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();

        //Set up lists
        cleansList = new ArrayList<cleanup>();
        absencesList = new ArrayList<absence>();
        urgencyList = new LinkedList<String>();
        entityAnswersList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        absNameList = new LinkedList<String>();
        schZoneList = new LinkedList<Character>();

        //Set up Models
        cleansListModel = new DefaultListModel();
        cleans.setModel(cleansListModel);
        absencesListModel = new DefaultListModel();
        absences.setModel(absencesListModel);
        DefaultListModel urgencyListModel = new DefaultListModel();
        urgency.setModel(urgencyListModel);
        DefaultListModel absNameListModel = new DefaultListModel();
        absName.setModel(absencesListModel);
        DefaultListModel entityAnswersListModel = new DefaultListModel();
        entityAnswers.setModel(entityAnswersListModel);
        DefaultListModel schZoneListModel = new DefaultListModel();
        schZone.setModel(schZoneListModel);

        //Static List Models
        DefaultListModel zoneNamesListModel = new DefaultListModel();
        zoneNames.setModel(zoneNamesListModel);
        DefaultListModel entityEntriesNamesListModel = new DefaultListModel();
        entityEntries.setModel(entityEntriesNamesListModel);

        //Action listeners
        addScheduledCleanupButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                new AddCleanups();
            }
        });
        addAbsenceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                new AddAbsence();
            }
        });
        cleans.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent listSelectionEvent) {
                int position = cleans.getSelectedIndex();
                if(position >=0) {
                    new AddCleanups(cleansList.get(cleans.getSelectedIndex()));
                    cleansList.remove(cleans.getSelectedIndex());
                }
            }
        });
        absences.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent listSelectionEvent) {
                int position = absences.getSelectedIndex();
                if(position >=0) {
                    new AddAbsence(absencesList.get(absences.getSelectedIndex()));
                    absencesList.remove(absences.getSelectedIndex());
                }
            }
        });
        absName.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent listSelectionEvent) {

            }
        });

        schZone.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent listSelectionEvent) {

            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(){
        //Visibility
        Interactive interactive = new Interactive();
        interactive.setVisible(true);
        loadFromFile();

    }
    public void addClean(cleanup C){ //Create a clean (Used by AddCleanups)
        cleansList.add(C);
        refreshLists();
    }

    public void addAbsence(absence A){ // Create an absence (Used by Add Absence)
        absencesList.add(A);
        refreshLists();
    }

    void refreshLists() { // Refreshing all lists when a change happens
        cleansListModel.removeAllElements();
        absencesListModel.removeAllElements();
        int counter = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;
        int counter3 = 0;
        int counter4 = 0;
        for(cleanup c : cleansList) {
            cleansListModel.addElement(c.getCode());
            schZoneList.add(c.getZone());
            if(c.getZone() == 'A') {
                //if the date is later than now && if the date is later than that of current urgency change the color accordingly
                //R >= 5 weeks; 5 < Y <= 3 weeks; G <= 2 weeks;
            } else if(c.getZone() == 'B') {
                //if the date is later than now && if the date is later than that of current urgency change the color accordingly
            } else if(c.getZone() == 'C') {
                //if the date is later than now && if the date is later than that of current urgency change the color accordingly
            } else if(c.getZone() == 'D') {
                //if the date is later than now && if the date is later than that of current urgency change the color accordingly
            }
            counter = counter + c.getBags();
            //if month is this month counter2 = counter2 + c.getBags();
            counter3++;
            counter4 = counter4 + c.getTime();
        }
        for(absence a : absencesList) {
            absencesListModel.addElement(a.getCode());
            absNameList.add(a.getName());
        }
        entityAnswersList.add(counter);
        entityAnswersList.add(counter2);
        entityAnswersList.add(counter3);
        entityAnswersList.add(counter4);
    }
    private static void loadFromFile(){
        //File Input
        String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
        String path = "C:/Users//" + userHome + "/Documents";


        //Read
        try{
            BufferedReader readInput = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String line = readInput.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                String[] storeValues = new String[2];
                if(line.substring(0,1).equals("C")) {
                    //ADD DATE_CHECK
                    storeValues = line.substring(1).split(",");
                    if(storeValues[1].length() == 13) {
                        cleansList.add(new cleanup(storeValues[0], storeValues[1], storeValues[2]));

                    }
                } else{
                    storeValues = line.substring(1).split(",");
                    if(storeValues[1].length() == 13) {
                        //ADD DATE_CHECK
                        absencesList.add(new absence(storeValues[0], storeValues[1]));
                    }
                }
                line = readInput.readLine();
            }
            readInput.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
    public void save(File file, ArrayList<cleanup> cleans, ArrayList<absence> absences) throws IOException {
        String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
        String path = "C:/Users//" + userHome + "/Documents";
        file = new File(path);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        for(int i = 0; i <= cleans.size()-1; i++){
            writer1.write("C" + cleansList.get(i).getCode() + "," + cleans.get(i).getName() + "," + cleans.get(i).getNotes());
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <= absences.size()-1; i++){
            writer1.write("A" + absencesList.get(i).getName()+ "," + absencesList.get(i).getCode());
        }
    }
}
```

```
package GUI;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputMethodListener;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

public class AddCleanups extends JFrame {
    private JPanel bigPanel;
    private JTextField date;
    private JTextField name;
    private JTextField time;
    private JTextField zone;
    private JTextField bags;
    private JTextArea notes;
    private JButton saveButton;
    private JButton deleteButton;
    AbstractDocument doc;
    
    AddCleanups(cleanup c) {
        //Existing entry
        super("ACTU Beach Cleanups");
        this.setContentPane(this.bigPanel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();

        name.setText(c.getName());
        date.setText(c.getDate());
        time.setText(c.getTimeString());
        zone.setText(c.getZoneString());
        bags.setText(c.getBagsString());
        notes.setText(c.getNotes());

        //Button Configuration
        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {// Closes the Window
                dispose();
            }
        });
        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {// Creates and saves a new cleanup, then refreshes
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) { //int date, int time, char zone, int bags, String n, String no
                if((date.getText().length() + time.getText().length() + zone.getText().length() + bags.getText().length()) == 14) {
                    cleanup newClean = new cleanup(
                            parseInt(date.getText()),
                            parseInt(time.getText()),
                            zone.getText().charAt(0),
                            parseInt(bags.getText()),
                            notes.getText(),
                            name.getText()
                    );
                } else {
                    //message
                }
                //addClean(newClean);
                //refreshLists();
                dispose();
            }
        });

    }
    public AddCleanups() {
        //New Entry
        super("ACTU Beach Cleanups");
        this.setContentPane(this.bigPanel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();

        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {// Closes the window
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {// Creates and saves a new cleanup, then refreshes
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) { //int date, int time, char zone, int bags, String n, String no
                if((date.getText().length() + time.getText().length() + zone.getText().length() + bags.getText().length()) == 14) {
                    cleanup newClean = new cleanup(
                            parseInt(date.getText()),
                            parseInt(time.getText()),
                            zone.getText().charAt(0),
                            parseInt(bags.getText()),
                            notes.getText(),
                            name.getText()
                    );
                } else {
                    //message
                }
                //addClean(newClean);
                //refreshLists();
                dispose();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

```
package GUI;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class AddAbsence extends JFrame{
    private JTextField name;
    private JTextField code;
    private JPanel bigPanel;
    private JButton saveButton;
    private JButton deleteButton;

    public AddAbsence(absence a) {
        super("ACTU Beach Cleanups");
        this.setContentPane(this.bigPanel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();

        //Existing absence
        name.setText(a.getName());
        code.setText(a.getCode());

        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {// Closes window
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                /*boolean valid = false;
                for(int i =0; i <= cleansList.length()-1; i++) {
                    if(code.getText().equals(cleansList(i).getCode())) {
                        valid = true;
                    }
                 }
                 if(valid == false) {
                    //message
                 } else {
                 */
                absence newAbsence = new absence(
                        name.getText(),
                        code.getText()
                );
                /*
                }
                addAbsence(newAbsence);
                refreshLists();
                 */
                dispose();
            }
        });
    }
    public AddAbsence() {
        super("ACTU Beach Cleanups");
        this.setContentPane(this.bigPanel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();


        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                /*boolean valid = false;
                for(int i =0; i <= cleansList.length()-1; i++) {
                    if(code.getText().equals(cleansList(i).getCode())) {
                        valid = true;
                    }
                 }
                 if(valid == false) {
                    //message
                 } else {
                 */
                absence newAbsence = new absence(
                        name.getText(),
                        code.getText()
                );
                /*
                }
                addAbsence(newAbsence);
                refreshLists();
                 */
                dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not do a huge code dump here and expect folks to debug it for you.  Prepare a working example as a [mre] and explain what problems you are having.  Keep the code short.  And before posting again, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: *"assignment (due pretty soon)"* That's a fact which is only of relevance to you, and mentioning it is ***less*** likely to get help. The reason is that the implication is that you feel your question is of higher priority than that of other people who have better time management skills, while most people prefer helping those .. with good time-management. I suggest you [edit] to remove that.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, unsurprisingly, this is my first post: I'll rety. Sorry again for seeming to want someone to just debug out of nowhere.

Comment: Tip: Add @WJS (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. Note that you can [edit] the question at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it would be impossible for me to solve whatever issue you are having but here are some quick observations.

- `JList` is generic type but you are using it as a raw type.  That should be fixed.
- `DefaultListModel` is a generic type but you are using it as a raw type.
- you are ignoring Exceptions.

```
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
```

Don't do that.  Otherwise you'll be back here asking why your data is not being
processed when you haven't successfully read it.

- You declared your `main` entry point incorrectly.  It must have the `String[] args` array.
- I haven't noticed any access problems.

**Other things to consider.**

- By convention class names should begin with uppercase.
- Don't extend `JFrame`. Use an instance.
- It is usually best to layout your `JFrame` using `JPanels` and put your other Swing components in the panels.
- Make certain you debug each class separately to ensure they are doing what you expect. Also focus on edge cases where unexpected problems may arise.
- Breaking out your classes into different files can be good and bad.  Sometimes I find it cumbersome to work with too many files. You can put them all in a single file as long as only one is declared `public`.  That is the one that must have the same name as the containing file.  The others would just be `class SomeClass`.  That is also the class that should contain the `main` entry point. All your imports would also be in that file.

Check out [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for more information.